# How do I import a CSV file into an SQLite database with the sqlite3 gem for Ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite, csv, sqlite3-ruby

Here's an example of my .CSV file:

```
column1,column2
data,moreData
foo,bar
cats,dogs
```

Using Ruby and the sqlite3 gem, is there a way to make an SQLite database and import the .CSV data into it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parse CSV with the csv lib, then just insert it like normal.

```
require "sqlite3"
require 'csv'

db = SQLite3::Database.new ":memory:"

# Create a database
rows = db.execute <<-SQL
  create table users (
    name varchar(30),
    age int
  );
SQL

csv = <<CSV
name,age
ben,12
sally,39
CSV

CSV.parse(csv, headers: true) do |row|
  db.execute "insert into users values ( ?, ? )", row.fields # equivalent to: [row['name'], row['age']]
end

db.execute( "select * from users" ) # => [["ben", 12], ["sally", 39]]
```

Comment: Hm, it seems that, at the root of it, the script must loop through the CSV file and insert the rows/items into the database. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm sure you could use Ruby's enumerable methods (e.g. [#each_slice](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable:each_slice)) to make batches of say 500, and then execute all at once (you just need to make the right sql and match it with the right array.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe import/export of data via CSV is something that is done via the `sqlite3` gem itself. You get data into/out of Ruby objects via a CSV library, and then it's just a matter of reading/writing the data to the DB via `ActiveRecord`, or whatever ORM it is that you're using.

[FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) should do it for you in Ruby. If you happen to also be using Rails 3.2, FasterCSV is, I believe, the default implementation behind the scenes of Rails' `CSV` lib.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd need to parse the CSV file some other way. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You can call sqlite3 binary from ruby:

```rb
%x(
sqlite3 "#{pathToDatabase}" << EOF
.mode csv
.separator ',' "\\\\n"
.import "#{pathToCsvFile}" "#{csvTableName}"
EOF
)
```